# Regex to split or to find the Dictionary 'Like' elements in text

Tags: regex, text, split, findall, findstr

I have a string that is like

```
"Name: Abcde fghijk, College: so and so college, somewhere, on earth Department: I Dont Know, Designation: still to be decided"
```

and i need to output something like this.

```
[ 'Name: Abcde fghijk,' , 
'College: so and so college, somewhere, on earth' , 
'Department: I Dont Know,' , 
'Designation: still to be decided' ]
```

I,ve been trying to formulate somekind of regex to find or to split the elements in certain way like this

```
r"[^\s]*:.*?,"
```

which i could bring it to something like this

```
['Name: Abcde fghijk,','College: so and so college,','Department: I Dont Know,']
```

but it misses some part of it.

```
 "somewhere, on earth" and "Designation: still to be decided"
```

Can someone help out on this! I NEED SOMETHING LIKE **capture until one word before next : or till the end**

Comment: Try `\w+:.*?(?=\s*\w+:|$)` https://regex101.com/r/kyuxKH/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `re.findall` approach which seems to be working:

```py
inp = "Name: Abcde fghijk, College: so and so college, somewhere, on earth Department: I Dont Know, Designation: still to be decided"
matches = re.findall(r'\w+: .*?\s*(?=\w+:|$)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['Name: Abcde fghijk, ',
 'College: so and so college, somewhere, on earth ',
 'Department: I Dont Know, ',
 'Designation: still to be decided']
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\w+:` match leading label followed by colon
- `.*?` space followed by any content, up to, but not including
- `\s*` optional whitespace
- `(?=\w+:|$)` assert that what follows is another label: or end of input